# What is the result of measuring $\sigma_x$ on the state $|01\rangle+|10\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, measurement, textbook-and-exercises

I confused about how to calculate the *probabilities* and getting a certain result of measuring Bell's states with Pauli matrices as the operator. When you measure something, the state involved would be projected onto an eigenstate of the observable.

given $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (|01⟩ + |10⟩)$ as the state and
$\sigma_x = \left[\begin{matrix}0&1\\1&0\\\end{matrix}\right]$ as the observable.

if the probability is 1/2, how to calculate them actually? What is the state after measurement?

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this first requires rewriting whatever state you have in terms of the eigenstates of the operator in question.
$$
|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|+\rangle + |-\rangle)\\
|1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|+\rangle - |-\rangle)
$$
so that $|\psi\rangle$ becomes
$$
\begin{align}
|\psi\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Big( \frac{1}{2} (|+\rangle + |-\rangle)(|+\rangle - |-\rangle) + \frac{1}{2} (|+\rangle - |-\rangle)(|+\rangle + |-\rangle) \Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} (2|++\rangle - 2|--\rangle) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|++\rangle - |--\rangle) 
\end{align}
$$

Notice that this state still looks entangled in the $X$-basis, which is general property that entanglement cannot disappear just by rotating between bases.  The second thing is that when you say you want to measure $X$, you have written a single-qubit operator, but this a two-qubit state.  We can easily make it a two-qubit operator by taking the tensor product
$$
\text{X on the first qubit} \rightarrow X \otimes I\\
\text{X on the second qubit} \rightarrow I \otimes X
$$
Here it actually doesn't matter which qubit of the entangled pair we measure, because their states are maximally correlated in the $X$-basis.  Since the state's components are now expressed in terms of the eigenstates of either operator above, we can take the norm-squared of the amplitudes of the components of the state to see that we get either $|+\rangle$ (+1) or $|-\rangle$ (-1) with probability $1/2$ on either qubit we choose to measure.

---

See @KAJ226's post for the probability/measuring, below I'll explain how to get the eigenvectors

For the operators $Z$ and $Y$ the procedure is the same.  Note that the computational state $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ *are* the eigenstates of the $Z$ operator, so you don't need to rewrite them.  The eigenstates of the $Y$ operator are
$$
|y+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0\rangle + i|1\rangle)\\
|y-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0\rangle - i|1\rangle)
$$
so that the computational states, rewritten in the $Y$-basis, are
$$
|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|y+\rangle + |y-\rangle)\\
|1\rangle = \frac{1}{i\sqrt{2}} (|y+\rangle - |y-\rangle)
$$

To obtain the eigenvectors of any matrix (operator), you look for solutions of the following equation

$$
A|v\rangle = \lambda |v\rangle\\
(A - \lambda I) |v\rangle = 0
$$

where $A$ is an operator, $I$ is the identity matrix, $|v\rangle$ is a vector, and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.  This equation has solutions when the determinant of the matrix $A - \lambda I$ is 0.  As an example, for the $X$ operator

$$
det(X - \lambda I) = 0\\
det\begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & 1 \\ 1 & -\lambda \end{bmatrix} = 0\\
\lambda^2 - 1 = 0\\
\lambda = \pm 1
$$

Knowing the eigenvalues, we plug them back into the original equation to find the eigenvectors.  For the first eigenvalue $\lambda = +1$

$$
A|v\rangle = +1 |v\rangle\\
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix}
$$

which says that $a=b$, so that the eigenvectors of eigenvalue +1 are the vectors $a\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ for some scalar $a$.  But remember, these vectors are quantum states, which must be normalized, so we can find $a$

$$
\langle v | v \rangle = 1 = a^* a \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 2|a|^2  \\
\frac{1}{2} = |a|^2
$$

and we see that a simple solution is just that $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, which is the familiar normalization factor.  The state we have found is

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( |0\rangle + |1\rangle \big) \equiv |+\rangle
\end{align}
$$

So if an eigenvector of $X$ is $|+\rangle$, then applying $X \otimes I$ to the state $|+\rangle \otimes |\phi\rangle$ for arbitrary $|\phi\rangle$ yields $+1 |+\rangle |\phi\rangle$, which is an eigenvector of eigenvalue +1.

Comment: I would just like to add that for qiskit users, the tensor product would be reversed such that X on the first qubit: $I\bigotimes X$, and X on the second qubit: $X\bigotimes I$.

Comment: Is it the same if we want to measure Y and Z? May I know how you get the eigenstates of the operator. Sorry, I still don't understand how the calculation works. can you explain step by step for measuring the probability of X on the first qubit? What is the state after measurement ?

Comment: I added more to my post

Comment: thank you so much. I understood and convinced about the calculation made. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $ \sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ has two eigenvectors $|+ \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  $ and  $|- \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}  $ with the corresponding eigenvalues of $+1$ and $-1$, respectively.

According to the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule), the probability that we will get $+1$ on the first qubit which correspond to the $|+\rangle$ is $Tr( \rho M)$, where $\rho$ is the density matrix and in this case it is $\rho = |\psi \rangle \langle \psi|$, and $M$ is the projection operator onto the basis vector corresponding to the measurement outcome of $+1$ on the first qubit in this case. Calculating it out explicitly:

$$ \rho = |\psi \rangle \langle \psi | = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

\begin{align} M = |+\rangle \langle+| \otimes I = \bigg[ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \bigg] \otimes  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} &=  \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0  & 1\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}

And therefore,

$$Tr(\rho M) = Tr\bigg(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0  & 1\end{pmatrix} \bigg) = \dfrac{1}{2} $$

**UPDATE:** The state after measurement, $|\psi_{post}\rangle $, is going to be
\begin{align}
|\psi_{post}\rangle  = \dfrac{ M |\psi \rangle }{ \sqrt{prob(+1)}} = \dfrac{ \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0  & 1\end{pmatrix}   \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  }{ \sqrt{ 1/\sqrt{2} } } = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = |+ +\rangle 
\end{align}

Note that $|++\rangle = |+ \rangle \otimes |+\rangle = \bigg(\dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg) \otimes \bigg(\dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg) = \dfrac{|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle + |11\rangle }{2} $

---

This can be extended to measurement in $Y$ basis as well. But $ \sigma_y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i\\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and hence its two eigenvectors
are $|i \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i \end{pmatrix}  $ and  $|-i \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -i \end{pmatrix}  $ with corresponding eigenvalues of $+1$ and $-1$ respectively. Then the probability to see $+1$ on the first qubit can be again calculated by $Tr(\rho M)$ but here $M = |i\rangle \langle i| \otimes I $ which can be calculated explicitly as

\begin{align} M = |i\rangle \langle i| \otimes I = \bigg[ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i \end{pmatrix}  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i \end{pmatrix} \bigg] \otimes  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} &=  \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i \\ i & 1  \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -i & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -i\\ i & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & i & 0  & 1\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}

and hence

$$Tr(\rho M) = Tr\bigg(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -i & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -i\\ i & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & i & 0  & 1\end{pmatrix} \bigg) = \dfrac{1}{2} $$

---

**Update 2:**

If you want to measure in the $Z$ basis then it's trivial as you can already see the answer but we can follow the same procedure for  confirmation. $\sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $ and it has two eigenvectors $|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}$ and $|1 \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$ with two associate eigenvalues $+1$ and $-1$ respectively. Now to know the probability of getting the first qubit to be measured with $+1$ is $Tr(\rho M)$ where $\rho$ is similar as before, and $M = |0\rangle \langle 0| \otimes I$, which works out explicitly as

\begin{align} M = |0\rangle \langle 0| \otimes I = \bigg[ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \bigg] \otimes  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} &=   \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0  & 0\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}

Hence

$$Tr(\rho M) = Tr\bigg(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0  & 0\end{pmatrix} \bigg) = \dfrac{1}{2} $$

and the state after collapsed is:
\begin{align}
|\psi_{post}\rangle   = \dfrac{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0  & 0\end{pmatrix}   \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  }{ \sqrt{ 1/\sqrt{2} } } = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = |0 1\rangle 
\end{align}

This makes sense because we have $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{|01\rangle + |10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} $ and so if the first qubit is in the state $|0\rangle$ after measurement then this means that the state $|\psi \rangle$ has collapsed onto the eigenvector $|01 \rangle$, hence the reason why our calculation show $|01\rangle$ for $|\psi_{post}\rangle$. Similarly, if the read out indicates that the first qubit is a $|1\rangle$ then $|\psi_{post}\rangle$ would have been $|10\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I really appreciate it. May I know how to write the state after obtaining the result in Dirac notation? how to change from matrix to braket form ya ?

Comment: See my update portion of the answer.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: if we want to measure the second qubit of the state, using the collapse state, the probability of getting +1 will be 1 while the state after the measurement is still |++>. is this correct?

Comment: can you show the calculation for measuring Z-basis and the state after measurement? I get probability 1/2 with the state after the measurement is 1x4 matrix wich is 0 1 0 0 . is this correct ?

Comment: @EaraShahirah To your first question: yes. To your second question: I have added what you have asked in Update 2.

Comment: I have measured the second qubit using Z-basis for the collapsed state. I got probability 0 for measuring +1.  if this is correct, how should I write the state after measurement for this calculation because it should be an error when dividing with 0.

Comment: may you explain the meaning behind all of this measurement? how to say that the two entangled qubits are correlated to each other. actually, I need to understand this calculation for rewriting the EPRargument corresponds to Pauli operator.

Comment: should I said that , Measurement of operator A which is sigma-X will result in eigenvalue, +1, -1 with probability 1/2 and the state of particle x1 will be projected onto the |++ ⟩ when measuring +1 while state of particle x2 will be projected onto the ? I confused how to write this and relate with the collapse state. should I compare the measurement of XX, ZZ, XZ and ZX using the same eigen value for the second qubit measurement of collapse state or using different eigenvalue?

Comment: hope to hear from you soon @KAJ226

Comment: Regarding your question about dividing by 0, there is no further collapse by measurements in the Z-basis, so the post-measurement state is always |01>

Comment: hi, I don't really understand how can the post-measurement state is always |01>. can you explain more? @chrysaor4

Comment: The state |01> is not in superposition in the Z basis, i.e. IZ and ZI have outcomes -1 and +1 always, so there is no state collapse.

Comment: okay, I got it. Thank you so much.