# Probabilities of entangled state. Quantum measurement

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, measurement

I confused about how to calculate the PROBABILITIES and getting a certain result of measuring Bell's states with Pauli matrices as the operator. When you measure something, the state involved would be projected onto an eigenstate of the observable.

Given $|ψ⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (|01⟩ + |10⟩)$ as the state and $σy   = \left(\begin{matrix}0&-i\\i&0\\\end{matrix}\right)$ as the observable.

How to calculate probability on the first qubit actually? What is the state after measurement?

Comment: please use meaningful titles for your posts

Comment: this is essentially a duplicate of [Probabilities of entangled state](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14651/probabilities-of-entangled-state)

Comment: okay, noted. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $\sigma_Y$ has two eigenvalues $\pm 1$, so the one-qubit projectors for the measurement are
$$
\frac12(I\pm\sigma_Y).
$$
Since you're measuring a two-qubit state, you need to express the measurement projects on both qubits. Since you're doing nothing to the second qubit, that's just the identity matrix:
$$
P_{\pm}=\frac12(I\pm\sigma_Y)\otimes I.
$$
You can check that $P_++P_-=I\otimes I$.

Now measurement follows the standard formalism. The probabilities of getting either outcome are
$$
p_{\pm}=\langle\psi|P_{\pm}|\psi\rangle
$$
and the possible states after the measurement are
$$
|\psi_{\pm}\rangle=P_{\pm}|\psi\rangle/\sqrt{p_{\pm}}.
$$